# Browsers storing user login information - Is It Cookies?

Tags: web, cookies

When I "save this password" in my web browser, are the usernames and passwords stored in  cookies? If not, what mechanism is it?

Answer (score 3):

Passwords are not stored in cookies, they are stored by the browser itself

Cookies can store sessions,etc. but the password text is stored in a plaintext or encrypted format by the browser